# getParent().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment, android-progressbar

I have a problem with use ActionBarSherlock, fragment, and indeterminateprogressBar.
I Have a sherlockFragmentActivity with my fragmentpageradapter and pagertabstrip.

I want to display the indeterminate progress Bar when I press button in a fragment.
I declared the

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

in the SherlockFragment Activity, but when, in the fragment, call

```
 getSherlockActivity.getParent().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true)
```

i get an error.
If call in the sherlockFragmentActivity, the bar, work.

Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue,
I create method in FragmentActivity

```
public void progressOn() {
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
}
public void progressOff() {
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}
```

and and I have called them in the fragment with

```
((MainActivity) getSherlockActivity()).progressOn();
```

and

```
((MainActivity) getSherlockActivity()).progressOff();
```

thanks anyway